Constructing an isomorphism $H^{k}(M_1-W_1)\oplus H^{k}(M_2-W_2)\rightarrow H^{k}(M_1\# M_2)$
I'm back again. Let $M_1$ and $M_2$ be compact, orientable, connected smooth manifolds.
In trying to understand the first question of this question, I want to construct an isomorphism $H^{k}(M_1-W_1)\oplus H^{k}(M_2-W_2)\rightarrow H^{k}(M_1\# M_2)$ for $0<k<\dim(M_1)=\dim(M_2)$ (where $W_1$ and $W_2$ are the balls along which the connected sum is constructed). Now, I already know that $H^k(M_1\# M_2)\cong H^k(M_1-W_1)\oplus H^k(M_1-W_2)$, but this doesn't tell me much about how forms on $M_i-W_i$ give rise to forms on $M_1\# M_2$. My aim is that, the image of $([w],0)$ is compactly in the interior of the image of $M_1-W_1$ in $M_1\# M_2$ (and the same for $(0,[\eta])$. In particular, if $\{[x_i]\}$ and $\{[y_i]\}$ is a basis for $H^k(M_1-W_1)$ and $H^k(M_2-W_2)$ respectively, then if $h$ is the isomorphism, $h([x_i],0)\wedge h(0,[y_j])=0$ (the idea is that I would get forms with disjoint support). Moreover, it'd be nice if I could say that $\int_{M_1\# M_2}e_i=\int_{M_1-W_1}x_i$, where $e_i$ is a represenatitve of $h([x_i],0)$ (same thing for $y_i$).
The idea I had was to embed $M_1\# M_2$ in some $\mathbb{R}^n$ then use the fact that there exists regular domains $R_i\subseteq M_1\# M_2$ such that $R_i\cong M_i-W_i$ (proposition 9.29 of Lee) and so that $R_1\cap R_2=\partial R_1=\partial R_2$. I'd then use the tubular neighborhood theorem to extend a form on $R_i$ to the entirety of $\mathbb{R}^n$, and then pull it back to $M_1\# M_2$. My issue is that I have no idea how to show the fact that if my original form on $R_i$ is closed, then so must this form. I also don't know if this fulfills the other requirement even if it is. I'm not even sure if this makes sense.
